# Countdown Timer on Android Java

Tags: android-studio

I have a quiz application which I have a function that a certain category will only be available once every 24hours in just 15mins. Now I am planning to put a timer same on the flash sale of the eCommerce Application.

Been looking on the internet but those timer are not fix and it will start again from the top if you refresh your Activity. anyone can give me some advice on this matter it will also base the timer for the server time not device time :)

I have found some here in stackoverflow. I want this countdown will always start at 11:15AM and will ends at 11:00AM on the following day and start the countdown again at 11:15AM. It would be better if I can use timezone also that even they change their device time the timer won`t be affected.

```
private void start_countdown_timer()
{
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setLenient(false);


String endTime = "18.09.2017, 15:05:36";
long milliseconds=0;

final CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

Date endDate;
try {
    endDate = formatter.parse(endTime);
    milliseconds = endDate.getTime();

} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        startTime=startTime-1;
        Long serverUptimeSeconds =
                (millisUntilFinished - startTime) / 1000;

        String daysLeft = String.format("%d", serverUptimeSeconds / 86400);
        //txtViewDays.setText(daysLeft);
        Log.d("daysLeft",daysLeft);

        String hoursLeft = String.format("%d", (serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) / 3600);
        //txtViewHours.setText(hoursLeft);
        Log.d("hoursLeft",hoursLeft);

        String minutesLeft = String.format("%d", ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
        //txtViewMinutes.setText(minutesLeft);
        Log.d("minutesLeft",minutesLeft);

        String secondsLeft = String.format("%d", ((serverUptimeSeconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60);
        //txtViewSecond.setText(secondsLeft);
        Log.d("secondsLeft",secondsLeft);


    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
}.start();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your timer state in local storage (eg. shared preference ) at the time of refreshing your activity.  You need to do it activity life cycle onPause method. Then in onResume method, you  need to check the timer state whether it is already started or not and update the timer based on that.

Comment: do you have any reference on this? as of this moment I cannot visualize. even just a sample.

Comment: I have just given you an idea, unfortunately, don't have any reference. You can search github android quiz repo. I am providing you sample link https://github.com/kaushiknsanji/Bird_Quiz_App